# nspredicate problem with AND operation

Tags: iphone, ios, nspredicate

I am stuck  up with below line and i am not have much knowledge on coredata ,

```
`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(bookPath == %@) AND (accessed==%u)) AND (isCurrentSession==%u)", myString,[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],[NSNumber numberWithBool:_accessed]];`
```

upto now i sent two values to my predicate, in the above predicate i am using three values,

**My Question**: can we apply two AND operations in a single predicate, can any one provide some idea about this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're using a `%u` substitution (`unsigned int`), but you're substituting in an `NSNumber *`.  That will cause problems.  Either use `%@` for all of the substitutions, or don't box your `BOOLs` in `NSNumbers`.

Comment: thanks for your reply,your absolutely correct i modified the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to combine predicates with 'AND' and 'OR' to an arbitrary level of complexity. The formal parser grammar for the predicate syntax can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-CJBDBHCB).

For best performance you should order your predicate terms so that simple tests (e.g numeric comparisons) appear first in the format string and more complex tests (e.g. REGEX pattern matching) appear last.

Comment: Btw, you don't actually say in your question whether you have tried this and are having problems or whether you just want to know in advance.